# rxjs sample operator issue

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am currently learning rxjs and find that **sample** operator is not work as what I intend. Here is the sample code I have.

```js
const source = rxjs.interval(500); 
rxjs.interval(300)
    .pipe(
        rxjs.operators.sample(source)
    )
    .pipe(
        rxjs.operators.take(20)
    )
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

which as code runs get the result of

```
0 2 4 5 7 ...
```

However, I expect the result is

```
0 1 3 5 ...
```

based on the below picture reasoning.

[image]

So can someone explain to me how **sample** operator works and why the below test case will return `0 2 4 5 7 ...`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the first (# 0) interval emits after the set period. It does not emit the 0 value at subscription.

So the image you provides works correct except that the first emission should be skipped:

```
time:            0.    300ms.     600ms.     900ms.    1200ms.    1500ms     

300ms interval         #0         #1         #2        #3.        #4
500ms sample                   #0               #2                #4
```

An example to have more feeling regarding the timing: https://jsfiddle.net/8t4r3ev0/33/

Comment: my bad, from https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval, `The first emission is not sent immediately, but only after the first period has passed.`.